# Is this a correct expansion of the function $\cos(z)$ around $\frac{\pi}{2} $ where $z\in \Bbb{C}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to find an expansion of $f(z)=\cos(z)$ where $z\in \Bbb{C}$ around $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I first remarked that $f$ is analytic and thus we have given an expansion by $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{n!} \left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$$But now computing all the derivatives at $z_0$ we get that $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+1}$$and we are done.

Is this correct so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simpler to use the fact that\begin{align}\cos(z)&=\cos\left(\frac\pi2+\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)\right)\\&=-\sin\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)^{2n+1}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left(z-\frac\pi2\right)^{2n+1}.\end{align}